# C++ received char for integer type cause switch case went wrong

Tags: c++, char, int, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a simple program that will prompt user to input a number, then it will reply back to user that which number key has been key in. Inputs other than 0~9 should go to default case which has "Not allowed." message will be print as output. The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter number from 0~9: ";
    cin >>x;
    switch (x)
    {
    case 0: cout<< "0 is pressed.";break;
    case 1: cout<< "1 is pressed.";break;
    case 2: cout<< "2 is pressed.";break;
    case 3: cout<< "3 is pressed.";break;
    case 4: cout<< "4 is pressed.";break;
    case 5: cout<< "5 is pressed.";break;
    case 6: cout<< "6 is pressed.";break;
    case 7: cout<< "7 is pressed.";break;
    case 8: cout<< "8 is pressed.";break;
    case 9: cout<< "9 is pressed.";break;
    default : cout << "Not allowed.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So when I try to input non-integer such as 'a' or "abc", it will run the statement in case 0, instead of case default. Can anyone explain why? Isn't when an integer variable trying to store a character, it would take it's ascii as it's value? Hopefully someone are willing to explain the logic behind this. Thank you!

(I'm currently using getchar() and declaring variable x as char data type, as well as case '0' and so on to temporarily solve this problem. But I myself is interesting to learn the knowledge about this. Sorry if such post is duplicated, I tried to search and found none. Wish that my searching technique isn't that terrible.)

Comment: have a look here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-ignore

Comment: No, when "an integer variable trying to store a character" it doesn't "take it's ascii as it's value". That's not how `<<` works. But you still need the `default:` in case someone types in "42" as input, for example. You just need to add some code to check for invalid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is introduced in `c++11`, if `std::cin` extraction fails `x` is [zero initialised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

> **If extraction fails, zero is written to value** and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

Obviously providing a letter when number is expected leads to extraction failure.

If you are not using `c++11` and above then the value of `x` is whatever it was before the operation.

What you can do to rectify this is to read a `char` instead and compare it to `char` as well:

```
char x;
cout << "Please enter number from 0~9: ";
cin >> x;
switch (x)
{
    case '0': cout << "0 is pressed."; break;
    case '1': cout << "1 is pressed."; break;
    //..the rest of cases..//
    default: cout << "Not allowed.";
}
```

Alternatively, you could handle extraction failure and clear `std::cin` then prompt the user again:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int x;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter 1, 22 or 155: ";
        if (std::cin >> x)
            break;

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    switch (x)
    {
        case 1: std::cout << "1 is entered\n"; break;
        case 22: std::cout << "22 is entered\n"; break;
        case 155: std::cout << "155 is entered\n"; break;
        default: std::cout << x << " is not an option, good bye!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Now I know how and why does this happened!

Comment: A better fix would be to check the state of `cin`: if it's in fail state then do the default handling.  You will need to check this anyway in order to reset the state and continue with input, unless the program exits in this case

Comment: @M.M Sure thing

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to break it down:

```
int x; // will store 0 in x as it is the default value of int
cout << "Please enter number from 0~9: ";
cin >>x; // if you input a string this will fail, and cin should be in an error state, 
         // and the value of x is unchanged
switch (x)
{
  case 0: cout<< "0 is pressed.";break; //< x is 0
  ...
```

You should check if cin has error'd in order to handle strings:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
  //handle error
  cin.clear() // reset cin error flags
}
```

Comment: `int x` is non-class local variable which is not static or thread-local and as such it's initialized with indeterminate value which just happens to be `0` here.

Comment: @DanM `cin >> x` sets `x` to `0` if the input is not the right format.  (But it leaves `x` unchanged if no characters could be read at all, so the code is still bugged and should initialize `x`).

Answer (score 0):

once different type data enter in "cin" it takes default value of that type.

```
int x;
cout << "Please enter number from 0~9: ";
cin >>x;
```

input comes string, it return 0 as default value of int x.